# Unable to update the database using findAndModify

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm using Node.js with mongodb.

```
    var mongo = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
    var url = process.env.MLAB_URI;

    mongo.connect(url, function (err, db) {
      if (err) {
      console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err);
      } else {
    //HURRAY!! We are connected. :)
    console.log('Connection established');
    var sequence = db.collection('sequence')

    //Find and modify the sequence counter.
    var obj = sequence.findAndModify({
      query: {_id: 1},
      update: { $inc: {seq: 1}},
      new: true
    });

    console.log(obj);

    sequence.find({_id:1}).toArray(function(err,res){
      if(err)
        console.log(err);
      else
        console.log(res)
    });

     db.close();
  }
});
```

But the above code is not updating the database and the output of `obj` that is returned is `Promise { <pending> }` .
The complete output is

```
Connection established
Promise { <pending> }
[ { _id: 1, seq: 0 } ]
```

I need to update the value and retrieve the object . Is there any way to do that?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean the value of "seq" before update is 14 as well? You are trying to increment seq. It seems that it has incremented the value.

Comment: yes it was 14 even before. It works with just update command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please  change the `findAndModify` as mentioned below.

```
var obj = sequence.findAndModify(
  {_id: 1},
  {},
  {  $inc: {"seq": 1}},      
  {new:true, upsert:true}
);
```

**Second option to avoid promise:-**

> Comment the  console.log(obj);

```
var obj = sequence.findAndModify(
  {_id: "1"},
  {},
  {  $inc: {"seq": 1}},      
  {new:true, upsert:true}, function (err, doc) {
    if(err)
    console.log(err);
  else
    console.log(doc);
  }
);
```

You are referring the Mongo shell version and try implementing the same using NodeJS version. The NodeJS `findAndModify` version is little different.

In order to get the old value of `seq`, you can set the `new` flag to false and `doc.value.seq` gives you the old value (i.e. value before update).

```
sequence.findAndModify(
  {_id: "1"},
  {},
  {  $inc: {"seq": 1}},      
  {new:false, upsert:true}, function (err, doc) {
    if(err)
    console.log(err);
  else {

    console.log(doc);
    console.log(doc.value.seq);
  }
  });
```

Comment: Thank you! This is updating the data in my db, but it still prints the obj as 'Promise { pending }'. I'm not sure why that is.

Comment: The Promise is because of this "console.log(obj);".

Comment: Can I not use the "obj" object to retrieve the current value of 'seq' by using  'obj.seq' ?

Comment: Basically this is what I'm trying to implement. [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/)

Comment: Updated the answer. Set new:false and use console.log(doc.value.seq) to get old value.

Answer (score 0):

change to

```
var obj = sequence.findOneAndModify({
  _id: 1,
  update: { $inc: {seq: 1}},
  upsert: true
});
```